# Why is the MongoDB Node Driver generating instance pool destroyed errors?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

When I run the following code I am getting the error message '**MongoError: server instance pool was destroyed**'.  Any idea why or how to fix this?

```
var csv = require('./importer.js');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var assert = require('assert');
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
var url = 'mongodb://.....';


MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {

    assert.equal(null, err);
    console.log("Connected correctly to server.");

    csv.foreach('data/airports.csv', function(airport){
        db.collection('airports').insertOne(airport, function(err, result) {
            if(err) {
                console.log(err)
            } else {
                console.log("Inserted: " + airport.ident);
            }
        });
    });

    db.close();
});
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

`csv.foreach` and the `insertOne` calls are (presumably) both async, so you're calling `db.close()` before your inserts have completed.

You need to come up with a way of waiting to call `db.close()` until all your inserts' callbacks have been called. How to do that depends on how your csv module works, but using something like the [async module](https://github.com/caolan/async) can help with the async flow control.

Answer (score 2):

I have same issue, after calling 'db.close()' together with async npm, this problem is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `for...of` instead of `forEach`. This solved my problem, although I am using async/await.