# server instance pool was destroyed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I Wrote a log service, nodejs + mongo (mongoose), then run for a period of time (7, 8 hours), there will be "server instance pool was destroyed" error, poolsize set to 2000.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39029893/why-is-the-mongodb-node-driver-generating-instance-pool-destroyed-errors will this link help you ?

Answer (score 0):

this happens when you accidentally call 'close()' on your client database and then try to access a collection for a query