# MongoError "server instance pool was destroyed"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, mongodb, typescript

Im trying to code an angular app that gets information from fullcontact API as a json and insert that to mongodb.I can successfully get json but when i try to insert it to mongodb.I solved other problems but stuck in this one.

```
 ERROR :
       MongoError {name: "MongoError", message: "server instance pool was destroyed", stack: "MongoError: server instance pool was destroyed↵   …    at http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:60:12"}



Kisiler.js 
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var Server = mongo.Server,
Db = mongo.Db,
BSON = mongo.BSONPure;

var server = new Server('localhost', 27017, {auto_reconnect: true});
db = new Db('kisidb', server);

db.open(function(err, db) {
if(!err) {


console.log("Connected to 'kisidb' database");
db.collection('kisiler', {strict:true}, function(err, collection) {
if (err) {
console.log("The 'kisiler' collection doesn't exist. Creating it with 
sample data...");
}
});
}
});

exports.kisiEkle = function(veri) {
var deger = new Object();
var deger = veri;
db.collection('kisiler', function(err, collection) {
 collection.insert(deger, {safe:true}, function(err, result) {
if(err){
console.log(err);
}else {
console.log(result);
}
});

});
}


user.component.ts 

const kisi = require('../../../../routes/kisiler');

// user.component.ts

console.log(data);  // type of data is json.
kisi.kisiEkle(data);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the MongoDB Node Driver generating instance pool destroyed errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39029893/why-is-the-mongodb-node-driver-generating-instance-pool-destroyed-errors)